# What is the right way to restart GlassFish 4?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, glassfish, glassfish-4

When I need to restart GF 4.0 I do

```
asadmin restart-domain
```

However, if there is running code at this time, for example if someone started database transaction and did half of this transaction? Will GF wait until all running threads finish their job?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, if you gracefully shut down glassfish (using asadmin executed graceful commands), it will wait for all current requests to finish as well as prevent new requests.

Comment: Could you provide any reference to documentation?